# How to download twitter bootstrap glyphicons?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

How to download twitter bootstrap glyphicons?
I want use it like images . Not like fonts.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about help in downloading something instead of programming.

Comment: As the answer below says, the PNG icons are there, but the site shows glyphs using an SVG font version (look in the CSS) which may be a good reference if you want to see how they look in that format.

Comment: I had success downloading the [icon font](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/raw/v3-dev/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg) and converted it using [Iconly](https://iconly.io/tools/font-to-icons-converter).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go directly to Glyphicons' website: http://glyphicons.com/

In the left sidebar, look for "**Glyphicons Free**" where you can download 470 icons in PNG format.

Comment: This option is no longer available,

Comment: As alternative you can download bootstrap version 3.3.7 and you can find them in fonts folder